# How to make a variable belong to a range Netlogo

Tags: range, rounding, netlogo, intervals

I have a turtle who can eat different amount of food for every tick, updating its stomach content every time. I would like to round the stomach content value so that it belongs to a range x.

this is the forage function that updates the stomach-content :
to forage

```
  ;; item=0.064g

  set patch-n random-float 100 
  if patch-n <= 8 [set stomach-content (stomach-content + 0.00) ] ; does not find any item
  if patch-n > 8 and patch-n <= 99 [set stomach-content (stomach-content + 0.192) ] ; finds 3 items
  if patch-n > 99 [set stomach-content 0.4 ]; full stomach

  ifelse stomach-content >= 0.132
  [set fat-reserves (fat-reserves + 0.132 ) set stomach-content (stomach-content - 0.132)]

  [set fat-reserves (fat-reserves + (stomach-content * 1)) set stomach-content 0] ;;
set fat-reserves (fat-reserves - (8 * bmr)) ; metabolic rate removes fat from fat reserves

end
```

the range I would like the stomach-content to belong to is

```
 set x (range 0 0.4 0.04)
```

Is there a way to make my stomach-content value to be in this finite range of 11 values?

Something like to round stomach-content to the nearest value with mod=0.04 in the interval (0 , 0.4)

Answer (score 4):

You could do something fancy with the `mod` reporter, but if you don't need it to be super fast, the following is easy enough, and also more flexible, as it would work with any list of values:

```
to-report nearest-in-list [ the-value the-list ]
  report first sort-by [ [a b] ->
    abs (a - the-value) < abs (b - the-value)
  ] the-list
end
```

You can then use it like this:

```
observer> show nearest-in-list 0.11 (range 0 0.4 0.04)
observer: 0.12
observer> show nearest-in-list 0.021 (range 0 0.4 0.04)
observer: 0.04
observer> show nearest-in-list 0.02 (range 0 0.4 0.04)
observer: 0
```

Note that, in case of ties (like with `0.02` in the example, which is halfway between `0` and `0.04`) it gives you the lowest value.